# HTML Email Button

Tags: html, css, email, button

very new here so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I would like an HTML button that opens a users native email client with the To: field prepopulated.

```
<form>
  <button class="button-21"  action="mailto:email@hotmail.com" type="submit"> Contact</button>
</form>
```

Here is the accompanying CSS:

```
.button-21 {
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #3eb2fd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(1deg, #4f58fd, #149bf3 99%);
  background-size: calc(100% + 20px) calc(100% + 20px);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: CircularStd, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, background-position 0.2s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button-21:active,
.button-21:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button-21:hover {
  background-position: -20px -20px;
}

.button-21:focus:not(:active) {
  box-shadow: rgba(40, 170, 255, 0.25) 0 0 0 0.125em;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### [action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) is a form's attribute for submission. You should move the action attribute from the button to the form.

```css
.button-21 {
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #3eb2fd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(1deg, #4f58fd, #149bf3 99%);
  background-size: calc(100% + 20px) calc(100% + 20px);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: CircularStd, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, background-position 0.2s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button-21:active,
.button-21:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button-21:hover {
  background-position: -20px -20px;
}

.button-21:focus:not(:active) {
  box-shadow: rgba(40, 170, 255, 0.25) 0 0 0 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:email@hotmail.com">
  <button class="button-21" type="submit">Contact</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<form>
  <button class="button-21"  onclick="location.href='mailto:test@gmail.com';" type="button"> Contact</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="mailto:email@hotmail.com">
        <button class="button-21"   type="submit"> Contact</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as a button inside a form, you can also use a link for this:

```html
<a href="mailto:email@hotmail.com">Contact</a>
```